# NiFi not launching

Tags: apache-nifi

```
INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Apache NiFi is currently running, listening to Bootstrap on port 20740, PID=31405
```

That means NiFi is running, and I can see its log in `logs/nifi-app.log`.

The UI is available at https://servername:9443/nifi. It successfully initiated communication with Bootstrap.

But i have this error, and the UI fails to appear. Do you have any solutions?

```
Failed to invoke @OnEnabled method of JettyWebSocketServer[id=01591009-1d2b-177f-e304-a7cc87d735ce] due to java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

Answer (score 3):

"java.net.BindException: Address already in use" means a port is already in use by something else on your system.

In this case it shows that it is coming from the JettyWebSocketServer controller service which is trying to bind to port 9998.

You can use "netstat -lntp" to see what is using port 9998. It could also be possible that you have more than one instance of the controller service with both of them configured with port 9998 and one of them is binging to it and the other fails.

Comment: but even when i killed the process and i tried to Change the port ! but always the same Error !

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)

Comment: Try running "netstat -lntp" to see all processors listening to ports and see what is on the port you think NiFi should bind to - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9252/determining-what-process-is-bound-to-a-port

Comment: tcp        0      0 servername:9443        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4196/java

Comment: that's for nifi !! That's mean the port is used just for nifi ! when i stop nifi the port (9443) disappear

Comment: Ok so if nifi is starting successfully and binding to the port then what is the issue? Please show what nifi-app.log looks like after starting nifi

Comment: [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer NiFi has started. The UI is available at the following URLs:
 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer https://servername:9443/nifi
 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.BootstrapListener Successfully initiated communication with Bootstrap
 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Controller initialization took 33023314290 nanoseconds (33 seconds).
...

Comment: ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-2] o.a.n.c.s.StandardControllerServiceNode Failed to invoke @OnEnabled method of JettyWebSocketServer[id=b4d6c5fa-015b-1000-613d-bb32e73ad0b9] due to java.net.BindException: Address already in use
 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-2] o.a.n.w.jetty.JettyWebSocketServer JettyWebSocketServer[id=b4d6c5fa-015b-1000-613d-bb32e73ad0b9] Stopping JettyWebSocketServer.
 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-2] o.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector Stopped ServerConnector@5567129f{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:9998}

Comment: That error shouldn't be preventing NiFi from starting, it is an error starting the JettyWebSocketServer controller service which looks like it is trying to bind to port 9998 and that is the port that is already in use, so you'll need to check netstat for 9998

Comment: Can you post your entire nifi-app.log somewhere? It will be easier to understand what is happening if I can see the whole thing

Comment: how can i post a file here !?

Comment: you can post it somewhere else and put a link here, a lot of people use gist - https://gist.github.com/

Comment: See my answer, it doesn't have anything to do with NiFi's listening port. If it was, then the UI wouldn't even start up.

Comment: @BenYaakobi Right I already mentioned that in the comments here saying to look into why the JettyWebSocketServer can't bind to port 9998, but the person claims they can't reach the UI even though that should be unrelated

Comment: @BryanBende i tried to open an account in github but it stuck on verify account!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a Controller Service that fails... Try browsing your `flow.xml.gz` and check for any ControllerServices named `JettyWebSocketServer`. Change their `<state></state>` from `<state>ENABLED</state>` to `<state>DISABLED</state>` and try running NiFi again. 
You can tell it is a controller service by the `@enabled`annotation which invokes a method that needs to run when the controller service is enabled.

NiFi shouldn't fail to start because of a failing controller service but it seems to be the problem(probably a bug).

After it start back up, you can configure the controller service to run on a different port.

I also suggest, that if it is the case, that you open an issue to Apache about this since it seems like a pretty major bug.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190059/discussion-on-answer-by-ben-yaakobi-nifi-not-launching).